# Script for rename with date extract from EXIF

Tags: batch-rename

I have hundreds of folders containing photos.
I want to create a script that will change the name of each photo and video with the shooting date of it as follows: YYYY-MM-DD-Nameofthefileoriginal
I would like the script created to browse the subfolders automatically to do the operation and have a percentage bar to know where I am.

Thank you in advance for your precious help

A novice in programming

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use good old IrfanView. The batch rename command allows you to specify patterns including EXIF information. For example, the pattern $E36868(%y%m%d_%H%M%S)-K1-$N[4-9] adds year, month, day, minutes, hours, seconds, string "-K1-" and characters 4-9 of the original file name ($N). Check the help file of Irfanview for the various pattern options.